# Proof of alternate characterization of Schwartz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

In a book that I am reading called *"Integral Geometry and Radon Transforms"* by Sigurdur Helgason, Schwartz functions are defined by $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if for every polynomial $P$ and each integer $m \geq 0$,
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\left|\left|x\right|^m P(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n) f(x)\right| < \infty$$
The book then claims that the following can be "easily proved just by using the Fourier transforms": A function $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if for each pair $k, \ell \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\left|(1+\left|x\right|)^k(L^\ell f)(x)\right| < \infty$$
where $L$ is the Laplacian operator. How does one prove this?

Comment: "if"-part is obvious. So I think the note of using "the Fourier transform" is about the "only if"-part. Does it mean we use "the Fourier Transform" on the $(1+|x|)^k(L^lf)(x)$?